# Selecting results as a comma-separated string

Tags: php, beginner, array, php5

The below code is working correctly, however, I am not sure if the combination of `while`, `foreach` and `implode` is really necessary here or if the same can be achieved much simpler.

What I do here is fetching some data (text) from a db and the only thing I need is the results as a comma separated string.

Now even though this is working I was wondering if there is a direct way to get the results as a comma separated string since the arrays here are not needed for anything else.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT " . $languageFrm . " FROM TranslationsMain WHERE location LIKE ? ORDER BY sortOrder, " . $languageFrm);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $location);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$strTranslations = array();
while($arrTranslations = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $translations[] = $arrTranslations;
}
foreach($translations as $translation){
    array_push($strTranslations, $translation[$languageFrm]);
}
echo implode(",", $strTranslations);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two loops + an array + implode,
you could use a single loop, appending to a string the elements and a comma.
For a non empty result, there will be a trailing unnecessary comma, so chop it off at the end.

Trying to move the formatting logic into the query is not a great idea for two reasons:

- a database is not a formatting tool. Good separation of concerns suggests to avoid using the database for such purpose
- a query with string concatenation will most probably sacrifice portability. Your current SQL is nicely portable: it will work fine in probably any rdbms. It would be good to keep it that way

Comment: I was just reading through this. So to make sure I get it right, within my while loop I could just say $translations .= $arrTranslations . "," with $translations now being a standard variable ? If so, how would I get rid of the trailing comma in this case ? Should I use $translations = substr($translations, 0, -1) for that ?

Comment: Thanks, so the substr function I added should work. How about what I suggested for the while loop ? Will that cover the rest ?

Comment: Yes, like that!

Comment: I am sorry I just had a chance to test this now but it doesn't work this way. I removed the foreach loop and just put $translations .= $arrTranslations .","; in the while loop as you suggested but then the result is only ["Array","Array","Array","Array","Array"...] (it works correct in my original version). Did I miss something here ?

Comment: If I'm reading your code right, you need `$arrTranslations[$languageFrm]` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks ! I had tried that before as well but it still doesn't work. Something must be missing because whenever I switch back to the original code it works fine. Now when I use what you have in your last comment it returns undefined instead.

Comment: Never mind - I figured this out with what you suggested. Not sure what I had wrong there before, maybe it was a typo. Sorry for that and thanks again ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using one of the below queries removes the need to iterate over the result sets to construct the CSV strings. When a single result is expected, a `->fetch()` instead of `->fetchAll()` would do.

Conclusion: `implode` goes away, `while` and `for` loops go away the only iteration needed would be in case of multiple CSV result sets.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(columnName) FROM Table1; # for single column

SELECT CONCAT(columnA,",",columnB) from Table2; # for multi cols
```

You **might** have issues creating prepared statements for this; I don't know.

example for the first query:

```
<?php

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");

$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(columnName) FROM Table1");

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: This looks very interesting, esp. the first option but how would I echo the result of this (as a comma separated string) if you say both the while and the for loop are not needed ?

Comment: edited the answer to answer your question